# android - Does imageView.getDrawable returns what I set using imageView.setImageResource?

Tags: android

Does imageView.getDrawable returns what I set using imageView.setImageResource?

I try animate an image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/selected"
    android:oneshot="false" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_white"
        android:duration="500"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_red"
        android:duration="500"/>

</animation-list>
```

Then in code I do

```
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.item_animation);
    AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
    animationDrawable.start();
```

However, once I got an exception

> StateListDrawable cannot be cast to
>   android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable

But then I cleaned the project and it started working again.

Can you please verify if `getDrawable()` returns `setImageResource`??

There is `setBackgroundResource`/`getBackgroud` but it does not give me the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `getDrawable()` will returns the same drawable that you set on `setImageResource`.

regarding `setBackgroundResource/getBackgroud`

`setImageResource()` is a member method of class `ImageView`,

while `setBackgroundResource/getBackgroud`
is a member method of class `View` so it will be included in every class that inherit from `View` class including `ImageView` class, if you tried to call both methods on same `ImageView` object they will overlap.